# CUDA threads in a wrap

Tags: cuda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CUDA threads in warp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268988/cuda-threads-in-warp)

Hai ,

Does the 32 threads in a warp run parallel on one multiprocessor 
and does it  need a synchronization?. I have doubt on these questions  and can some one tell 
how the 32 threads execute in the multiprocessor.

Thank you.